# "Loaded the controller nib but the view outlet was not set."

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, xib

I can't figure what's wrong : I'm trying to get to another view with a button's UIAction.

My view controller contains a UIScrollView IBOutlet. I created a .xib file for this view controller.

In this .xib I customized the class as my SettingsController class.

But now, with this configuration (I have scrollView, searchDisplayController and view as my outlets) I don't know how I must connect this to get it work. Please help !

Thanks a lot for your advices

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As i can see from you post, you have not connected some properties with objects in you nib file.

Open you second .xib in Interface Builder.
Check if UIView is connected to your File's owner. If not, just drag with right mouse button (or cmd+left mouse button) from File's owner to UIView and connect to view property. *(May be you should drag in another direction, from UIView to File's owner, i cannot remember now)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm facing this problem : both links from File's Owner->View or View->File's Owner don't exist. I mean, when I try to connect them, nothing happens..

Comment: @RobinDreux, in your post you have mentioned, that you have set the SettingsController class in your .xib. For what item did you set this class? For `UIView` or for `File's owner`?

Comment: No I've set the SettingsController (which is a subclass of UIViewController) class to my UIViewController in the .xib. Then I added a view to this ViewController. Is it wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

To clarify for anyone else - if you're making your own custom View Controller class with interface builder like this:

- MyViewController.h
- MyViewController.m
- MyViewController.xib

you need to make sure your .xib knows what class it's associated with.

Select your .xib file -> click File's Owner under Placeholder -> on the right Navigation pane, click on the third icon from the left (aka. the Identity Inspector) and type in your controller class name (ie. MyViewController) under Custom Class. Save the .xib file.

**If you are using UITabBarController with multiple UIViewControllers (each w/ their own nib files), you also need to set the UIViewController class file inside your UITabBarController nib for each ViewController.**

[image: viewcontrollerclass]

*Then* you can connect your outlet properties.

Check out the section "Create New UI Classes in Xcode": http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just missed to set the correct class to the File's Owner.